# GradientPaint not working with itextPdf

Tags: java, swing, itext

I work with the last version of **itextPdf**. And all **used to work fine** I don't know when it has begun to trouble.

I have that method to converts to pdf a **GraphePinScene** object.

```
public void toPdf(Scene scene, float clipWidth, float clipHeight, String path) 
{
    float pageWidth = (float) scene.getView().getWidth();
    float pageHeight = (float) scene.getView().getHeight();

    double xScale = 1.0;
    double yScale = 1.0;
     Document d = new Document();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(d, new FileOutputStream(new File(path)));
        d.open();
        PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();

        //scaling
        if (pageWidth > PDF_MAX_WIDTH) {
            xScale = (double) (pageWidth / PDF_MAX_WIDTH);
            pageWidth = PDF_MAX_WIDTH;
        }
        if (pageHeight > PDF_MAX_HEIGHT) {
            xScale = (double) (pageHeight / PDF_MAX_HEIGHT);
            pageHeight = PDF_MAX_HEIGHT;
        }

        Graphics2D g2d = new PdfGraphics2D(cb, pageWidth + clipWidth, pageHeight + clipHeight);
        g2d.scale(xScale, yScale);
        scene.paint(g2d);

        g2d.dispose();
        d.close();
}
```

And the scene object contains some Widgets. All widgets are included in the pdf only the ones that are created with **GradientPaint** are not imaged in the pdf file, this is one of the widgets:

```
public final class SecondaryStationWidget extends IconNodeWidget {

    //Staff

    @Override
    protected void paintWidget() {
        Graphics2D g = getGraphics();
        RenderingHints rh = new RenderingHints(
                RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        rh.put(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
        g.setRenderingHints(rh);
            g.setPaint(new GradientPaint(44, 29, new Color(154, 191, 239), 88, 58, new Color(17, 74, 148), true));
            g.fill(new RoundRectangle2D.Double(1, 2,
                    88,
                    58,
                    10, 10));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probleme has been resolved by changing (forcing) the background of those kind of widgets (in the constructor).

```
setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 1)); //Remove
setBackground(Color.WHITE);  //Add
```